# Please help move WPF trigger behavior to Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, triggers

The WPF code:

```
 <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>
```

Can you write the same in Silverlight? Please dont vote to close this question.
Thanks!

Comment: What's about Storyboard?

Comment: VSM? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Or... you can install the "Blend SDK" (it's free), which extends Silverlight's triggers and allows you to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not supported in Silverlight. You can use a IValueConverter to change the value to the correct color.